# Why is isPasswordValid always false in NestJS using argon2 to verify password hash?

Tags: nestjs, bcrypt

I'm working on a NestJS project where I'm using the argon2 library to hash and verify passwords. I'm using the LocalStrategy provided by the @nestjs/passport package to validate the user's credentials.

However, I'm facing an issue where isPasswordValid is always false even when the password is correct. I have set a breakpoint at the line `const isPasswordValid = await argon2.verify(user.password, password);` and found that isPasswordValid is always undefined. I have verified that the user object is being fetched correctly from the database and that the password hash values look identical.

bcrypt.compare() also have the same issue.

Here's the relevant code:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne(username);
    console.log('User found:', user);
    console.log('Provided password:', password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  
    const isPasswordValid = await argon2.verify(user.password, password); 
    console.log('Is password valid:', isPasswordValid);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  
    return user;
  }
}
```

Want to know how to fix that

Comment: that has nothing to do with nestjs but nodejs, btw.

Comment: that's sounds like a misusage of `argon2.verify`. Make sure you've followed their docs properly

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The test case works well in my project with the same method: import * as argon2 from 'argon2';

async function testArgon2() {
  const password = 'test-password';
  console.log('Original password:', password);

  const hash = await argon2.hash(password);
  console.log('Hashed password:', hash);

  const isValid = await argon2.verify(hash, password);
  console.log('Is password valid:', isValid);
}

testArgon2()
  .then(() => console.log('Test completed.'))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Test failed:', error));

Comment: this is a nestjs project btw too